# Params vs. List<T>, When should I use params keyword and when to use List<t>

Tags: c#-3.0

I am developing a card game.

In this card game the player can set down few cards in the same turn.

I have a function called SetCardsDown(....)

The card collection parameter can implemented by params keyword or List type.

In which implemenation should I use?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`params` as it will give you the ability to pass in an array. It doesn't seem like you would want to pass in a list because that would give you extra functionality on the parameter that doesn't make sense. Like `Add` for example.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use `IEnumerable<T>`. That's the most flexible and least restrictive. Once you move to C# 4 (and you should) that will allow callers to use LINQ.

EDIT: Or you can use LINQ with 3.5. But unless you are forced to use something else, move to .NET 4.

Comment: This way has its faults. For example you can't call it with a single card without doing `SetCardsDown(new []{card})`. But based on the method name that might not make sense.

Comment: @Joel - Yes, but the OP said 3.0.

Comment: @TrueWill - He said C# 3.0; not .NET Framework 3.0. The C# 3.0 compiler is part of VS2008; which can also have .NET Framework 3.5 + LINQ.

Comment: I didn't understand.. are you suggesting to create a new collction type for this mission? that inherits from IEnumerable<T>?

Comment: @Guy - There's no need to. `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, and arrays can also be passed.

Comment: Yes I know, the question is if I really need all rhe functionallity of a list

Comment: @Guy - you can overload the function, so that you have a params version that then calls the IEnumerable version. Best of both worlds.